# Deal with input errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native.

I need to create the front-end part of an app used to manage products. In this app, a specific screen lets users add a "new product".

I've almost finished the UI part, but I now need to show errors to the user when something is wrong with its input (a missing product ID, a description with less than 10 characters, etc.).

Here's my objective: when the user clics the "publish" button, I check all the inputs. If the input is ok -> nothing happens, if the input contains an error -> the field turns red.

To achieve this, I need to work with states. Here should be an example for the title:

```
style={[style.inputText, {color: this.state.titleColor}]}
```

And I can change the state.TitleColor if something is wrong with the title input.

The problem is that I don't want to create a specific state for each input (titleColor, IDColor, descriptionColor, etc.).

How can I do a common state for inputs that are correct, and an other state for inputs that are wrong? I thought of using an array (with inputCorrect:[] ;
InputWrong:[]), but I do not know exactly how to deal with it.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a form library to help you with state and validation. I personally like [formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik), but I've heard good things about [react-final-form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) as well (both are compatible with React Native).

Libraries like this make it easier to manage validation and input state, because they manage the state for you and tell each of your fields whether they're valid or not (passing appropriate error messages if needed).

It's still up to you to build the UI that displays the errors, but having the logic taken care of is a huge help. The formik docs have some good examples showing you how you would achieve your goal of changing a field color to red if that field has errors.

There is a bit of a learning curve to understand how to use these libraries well, but it's well worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Shane. It's a good idea but I already have my validators and there aren't many, so I think that I can manage them by myself.

Comment: These libraries don't actually handle the validation for you directly, so you could use your existing validation with them. What they do is hold the form state for you, watch for changes to the field values or form submit events, and then make it easy for all of the form's children (e.g. field components) to know whether they are valid, what their error messages are, etc. so they can display/style themselves accordingly. All things you'd otherwise have to manually implement yourself to achieve what you're after.