# Avoid using multiple states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native.

I'm making a form with some TextInputs.

When the user clics the "publish" button, I check all the inputs. If the input is ok -> nothing happens, if the input contains an error -> the field turns red.

To achieve this, I need to work with states. Here should be an example for the title:

```
style={[style.inputText, {color: this.state.titleColor}]}
```

And I can change the state.TitleColor if something is wrong with the title input.

The problem is that I don't want to create a specific state for each input (titleColor, IDColor, descriptionColor, etc.), like this:

```
titleColor: greyBlack,
IDColor: greyBlack,
descriptionColor: greyBlack
```

... and turn them red when they contain an error.

How can I do a common state for inputs that are correct, and an other state for inputs that are wrong? I thought of using an array (with inputCorrect:[] ;
InputWrong:[]), but I do not know exactly how to deal with it.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Did you need to post this question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474738/deal-with-input-errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate state from view. Whether the input has an error or not is state; whether it's red or not is view. Something like `{color: this.state.titleError ? errorColor : undefined }`.

Comment: It is not exactly my question. I know how to do that, but how can I avoid doing a specific state for each text input. Not doing this.state.titleError but a general this.state.inputError ? then turn red.

Comment: Nope ! Some must have more than 5 characters, others simply not be empty, etc.

Comment: OK, so how about creating a component to render one input, and pass it the validation function as a prop?

Answer (score 0):

Once you modify a field's value, a state modification and a re-render will occur. In order to get the color, you can dynamically invoke a validation function when you are rendering.

Here is a small example - https://codesandbox.io/s/4wx0xxv624

Answer (score 0):

If there is a lot of textInput that need validation, might consider create child component for them with different validation rules, and let the child component control the styling based on the validation result.